# Потоки пользователей мешают друг другу в ТГ боте

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Я пишу бота для Телеги и ловлю баг используя этот код:

```
    import telebot
    import config
    import random
    import threading
    import sqlite3 as sl
    from telebot import types
    
    bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)
    print('Runned test bot')
    
    qesqty = len(config.QUESTIONS)
    
    check = False
    allballs = 0
    continuevar = ["Начнём!" , "Почти готово!" , "Последний вопрос!" , "Продолжим!" , "Далее!"]
    
    
    def errorMSG(message, ERRCODE) :
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id , 'Похоже, что-то сломалось. Подождите, мы всё починим! Код ошибки: ' + ERRCODE + '‍')
    
    def ask(message) :
        answer = 0
        check = False
    
        def true(message) :
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id , 'Правильно!')
    
        def false(message) :
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id , 'Нет!')
    
        def answvar(message , answers , var1 , var2 , var3 , var4) :
            answers = answers.replace("{" , '')
            answers = answers.replace("}" , '')
            answers = answers.replace("'" , '')
            answers = answers.replace("," , '\n')
            str1 = 'Варианты ответов: \n' + answers
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width = 2 , resize_keyboard = True)
            item1 = types.KeyboardButton("1")
            item2 = types.KeyboardButton("2")
            item3 = types.KeyboardButton("3")
            item4 = types.KeyboardButton("4")
            markup.add(item1 , item2 , item3 , item4)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id , str1.format(message.from_user , bot.get_me( )) , parse_mode = 'html' ,
                             reply_markup = markup)
    
        @bot.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
        def lalala(message):
            nonlocal answer
            nonlocal check
            answer = 0
            if message.chat.type == 'private':
                if message.text == 'LOL!':
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'LOOL')
                elif message.text == '1':
                    check = True
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы выбрали вариант 1')
                    answer = 1
                elif message.text == '2':
                    check = True
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы выбрали вариант 2')
                    answer = 2
                elif message.text == '3':
                    check = True
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы выбрали вариант 3')
                    answer = 3
                elif message.text == '4':
                    check = True
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы выбрали вариант 4')
                    answer = 4
                else :
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Сорян, я незнаю что ответить ')
            else:
                errorMSG(message, 'VAR_ERR')
                answer = 0
        def asking():
            nonlocal answer
            con = sl.connect('my-test.db')
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS results(name TEXT, score INTEGER)""")
            con.commit()
            nonlocal check
    
            global allballs
            currq = 1
            nextq = 2
            score = 0
            allballs = 0
            for i in range(qesqty):
                while answer != 0 or nextq == currq + 1:
                    answer = 0
                    if (currq == 1):
                        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                                         str(continuevar[0]) + ' ' + str(currq) + ' вопрос: ' + config.QUESTIONS.get(currq))
                    elif (currq == qesqty - 1):
                        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                                         str(continuevar[1]) + ' ' + str(currq) + ' вопрос: ' + config.QUESTIONS.get(currq))
                    elif (currq == qesqty):
                        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                                         str(continuevar[2]) + ' ' + str(currq) + ' вопрос: ' + config.QUESTIONS.get(currq))
                    else :
                        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, str(continuevar[random.randint(3, 4)]) + ' ' + str(
                            currq) + ' вопрос: ' + config.QUESTIONS.get(currq))
                    answers = str(config.VARIANTS.get(currq))
                    threading.Thread(target = answvar, args = (message, answers, '1', '2', '3', '4')).start()
                    # answvar(message, answers, '1', '2', '3', '4')
                    nextq += 1
                while answer == 0 or nextq != currq + 1:
                    if check == True:
                        ans = config.ANSWERS
                        balls = config.BALLS
                        # print(config.BALLS.get(currq))
                        print(currq , end = ' ')
                        print(answer)
                        allballs += int(config.BALLS.get(currq))
                        if int(answer) == int(ans.get(currq)) and int(answer) != 0:
                            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Правильно!')
                            score += int(balls.get(currq))
                        else :
                            bot.send_message(message.chat.id , 'Нет!')
                        if (currq < len(config.QUESTIONS)) : currq += 1
                        check = False
            # nextq = 2
    
            userdata = [str(message.from_user.first_name) , int(score)]
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO results VALUES(?, ?);" , userdata)
            con.commit( )
    
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id , 'Тест пройден! Ваш результат: ' + str(score) + ' из ' + str(
                allballs) + '. Процент выполнения: ' + str(score / allballs * 100) + ' %')
    
        asking()
    
    
    @bot.message_handler(commands = ['game'])
    def startgame(message) :
        x = threading.Thread(target = ask, args = (message,))
        x.start( )
    
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id ,
                         "Добро пожаловать, {0.first_name}!\nЯ - <b>{1.first_name}</b>, предлагаю вам пройти один тест. Начнём!".format(
                             message.from_user , bot.get_me( )),
                         parse_mode = 'html')
    
    
    @bot.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
    def welcome(message) :
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id , 'Добро пожаловать! Напишите /commands, и узнаете что я умею.')
    
    
    @bot.message_handler(commands = ['commands'])
    def welcome(message) :
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id , 'Запустить тест: /game \nКалькулятор: /calc')
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    @bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda call : True)
    def callback_inline(call) :
        try :
    
            # remove inline buttons
            # bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text=" Как дела?",
            #   reply_markup=None)
    
            # show alert
            bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id = call.id , show_alert = False ,text = "")
    
        except Exception as e :
            print(repr(e))
bot.polling(none_stop = True)
```

При одновременном клике по кнопке двумя юзерами, сообщение для одного юзера уходит другому.
Помогите, пожалуйста. Конфиг файл:

```
TOKEN = '****************************'

ANSWERS = {1:4, 2:3, 3:1, 4:2, 5:1}

BALLS = {1:2, 2:4, 3:1, 4:8, 5:25}

QUESTIONS = {1:'Question 1 text', 2:'Question 2 text', 3:'Question 3 text', 4:'Question 4 text', 5:'Question 5 text'}

VARIANTS = {1:{1:'1', 2:'2', 3:'3', 4:'4'}, 2:{1:'1', 2:'2', 3:'3', 4:'4'}, 3:{1:'1', 2:'2', 3:'3', 4:'4'}, 4:{1:'1', 2:'2', 3:'3', 4:'4'}, 5:{1:'1', 2:'2', 3:'3', 4:'4'}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в использовании разделяемых переменных, в частности `answer`. У вас обработчик для одного пользователя ее меняет, а потом обработчик другого использует.

Замените на глобальный dict с ключем `chat_id`:

```
user_answer = {}
user_check = {}

def ask(message) :
  ...
            user_answer[message.chat.id] = 0
            if message.chat.type == 'private':
                if message.text == 'LOL!':
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'LOOL')
                elif message.text == '1':
                    user_check[message.chat.id] = True
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы выбрали вариант 1')
                    user_answer[message.chat.id] = 1


 ...
```

И так везде - вместо `answer` используйте `user_answer[message.chat.id]` и аналогично для `check`. Tак у каждого будет своя копия переменной.

Comment: Или все глобальные переменные хранить в базе данных...

Comment: while user_answer[message.chat.id] != 0 or nextq == currq + 1 :
KeyError: 13176798**

Comment: @K_R_O_K_O_D_I_L_L_O, `KeyError` значит ошибка с ключом словаря, в том коде у вас словарь только `user_answer`, тогда `13176798` это `message.chat.id`, значит нужно или до этого момента заполнить словарь, указав тот ключ из `chat.id` либо поменять проверку, например на `user_answer.get(message.chat.id)`. Метод `get` вернет `None`, если ключа не будет

Comment: У второго юзера не работает проверка