# Телеграм бот python бот не может корректно работать с несколько пользователями одновременно

Tags: python, telegram-bot

```
@bot.message_handler(commands="start")
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введи свое имя")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, question1)
    
def question1(message):
    user_name = message.text
    # Дальше я эту переменную хочу записывать в какой то файл типа excel или еще какой то
```

но проблема в том что если бота одновременно используют 2 человека то эта переменная не успевая сохраниться запоминает только последнее значение, как это можно исправить, если отпишите подробно

Comment: Для пользователей больше одного нужно использовать асинхронное программирование. Уже есть готовая библиотека для этого aiogram. Либо используйте актуальную библиотеку, но запускайте несколько потоков

Comment: Вот именно по этой причине вам нужно реализовать конечный автомат(я уже устал это повторять в вопросах про телеграм :) и хранить в нем состояние каждого пользователя :)

Comment: Владимир Клыков Ну а как хранить ну к примеру в базе данных я сохранил айди пользователя и как потом его использовать?

Comment: Разве тут дело в асинхронности?

Comment: Владимир Клыков Можете привести пример как это сделать очень поможет)

Comment: примеры из telebot https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Какие инструменты мне понадобятся для написание "сложного" Telegram бота](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1267540/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-telegram-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0) ну и подобная проблема https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1302198/218971

Answer (score 4, accepted):

сам разбирался с этим вопросом два дня, увидел случайно методы словарей решил почитать и вроде разобрался, тоже советую к прочтению, как в пример могу привести тебе это

```
user_dict = {}

class User:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.accumulation_rub = 0
        self.income_rub = 0
        self.expense_rub = 0
        self.profit_rub = 0
        self.memory_sum = 0
        self.memory_sum_old = 0

@bot.message_handler(commands=['help', 'start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите x')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, next_step_valuey)

def next_step_valuey(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id       
    name = message.from_user.id     
    userid = User(name)             
    user_dict[chat_id] = userid     

    valuex = message.text
    userid = user_dict[chat_id]
    userid.valuex = valuex

    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Введите y', parse_mode = 
    'html')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, next_step_valuesum)

def next_step_valuesum(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    valuey = message.text
    userid = user_dict[chat_id]
    userid.valuey = valuey

    valuewalletsum = int(userid.valuex) + int(userid.valuey)
    userid.valuewalletsum = valuewalletsum


    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'x {userid.valuex} \n'
                                      f'y {userid.valuey} \n'    
                                      f'sum {userid.valuewalletsum}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Не используйте message.chat.id в качестве пользователя!!!Он предназначен для групп, а для пользователей есть message.from_user.id
Если использовать message.chat.id в качестве пользователя в группе то при использования кнопки, у всех будет также, как и у вас(если сделать многоуровневые кнопки)
Советую использовать ассинхроный TeleBot либо же aiogram

Answer (score 0):

Для этого необходимо записать id отправителя и его сообщение в словарь

```py
def question1(message):
    dict = {}
    user_name = message.text
    user_id = message.chat.id
    d{user_id} = user_name
```

Comment: `messgae` != `message`

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял вопрос. Всё там нормально работает для разных пользоватаелей.
И в коде ошибка по-моему (если я правильно предположил ожидаемый результат)
Вы должны передавать в next_step_handler сообщение бота, на которе он будет ожидать ответ, а вы передаете сообщение пользователя.
То есть должно быть

```
@bot.message_handler(commands="start")
def start(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введи свое имя")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, question1)
```